# UITableViewCell with multiline input field?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I want to create a uitableview cell , with multiline input field (textview). Height of textview or cell should increase automatically as the user enter the text.

Comment: Just so I understand what you are asking : you want a UITableView where the user can edit the text in the rows. You then want the text field to expand to accommodate the text as required in real time?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there: this has been bugging me all day but I've just put something together that I think has cracked it. I'm assuming you know how to put a basic tableView together.

You need to add a UITextView to each row, and, crucially, make your tableViewController the delegate for each UITextView. Alongside an array of String values for each of the rows, you also need to have an array of heights (CGFloats) for each row. Another crucial aspect is to assign each textView a numerical tag equal to the indexPath.row for the cell which allows us to keep track of which textView we are dealing with. This will start out as an array of identical values, but the idea is that you update this array as needed when the text gets too big for the existing frame, as I will demonstrate below.

I then implemented the following two delegate functions together with a bespoke function to update the layout as required:

```
func updateLayout(forTextView: UITextView) -> Void {
    guard forTextView.tag < self.data.count else { return } // Make sure we're not going to try and access a value that does not exist

    self.data[forTextView.tag] = forTextView.text // Update our data array to reflect the new string value for the cell's text view

    let newHeight : CGFloat = forTextView.frame.height // The new cell height is based on the height of the text view
    let oldHeight : CGFloat = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: forTextView.tag, inSection: 0))!.frame.height // Retrieving the existing height of the cell

    self.heights[forTextView.tag] = newHeight + 2 // Set the new value in the heights array with a 1 point buffer
    // Now animate to ease the transition
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) { 
        for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
                // We only need to update the edited cell and all cells below it
                if indexPath.row > forTextView.tag {
                    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y + forTextView.frame.height + 2 - oldHeight), size: CGSizeMake(cell.frame.width, self.heights[indexPath.row]))
                }
                else if indexPath.row == forTextView.tag
                {
                    cell.frame = CGRect(origin: cell.frame.origin, size: CGSizeMake(cell.frame.width, self.heights[indexPath.row]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    // Update the cell and exit
    self.updateLayout(textView)
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // More complicated: we need to update the frame but also maintain focus in this textView as the user has not finished editing yet
    var textFrame : CGRect = textView.frame
    let newHeight : CGFloat = ceil(textView.contentSize.height)
    if newHeight - textFrame.height > 0 {
        textFrame.size.height = ceil(textView.contentSize.height)
        textView.frame = textFrame
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 5), animated: false)
        self.updateLayout(textView)
    }

    // This code puts an active cursor back at the end of the textView's text
    textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: textView.text.characters.count, length: 0)
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

The tricky part was getting the tableView's layout to update while keeping the cursor's focus in the field being actively edited.

I am very pleased with the result which gives a smooth transition when the text field needs to expand.

I'd rather not send you the full code as it's always better to put these things together yourself; however, if you get really stuck drop me a line and I'll send it over. All best!

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier approach than the above answer. Create a custom cell with UITextView as following:

```
private lazy var valueTextField: UITextView = {
    let textField = UITextView()
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 204/255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 204255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textField.textColor = .black
    textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textField.isEditable = true
    textField.isScrollEnabled = false
    textField.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    textField.delegate = self
    return textField
}()
```

Change properties according to your needs.

Now add this UiTextView inside the view. Something like:

```
view.addSubView(valueTextField)
```

Then create a callback similar to the following:

```
var textChanged: ((String) -> Void)?

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textChanged?(textView.text)
}

func textChanged(action: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    textChanged = action
}
```

And then in your TableViewController, inside cellForRowAt implement the callback and refresh the tableview using begin and end update calls:

```
(cell as! CustomCell).textChanged {[weak tableView] (newText: String) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

That's it. Your textView should be working as expected.